# ActionHandler error in FXML JAVAFX

Tags: java

I have made a basic login screen in netbeans using javafx and scenebuilder 2.0! by copying a youtube tutorial.

```
<Button id="btnLogin" layoutX="146.0" layoutY="243.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#initialize" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="Login" />
```

as shown above, netbeans underline "#initialize" and give the folowing error "Handler method is not accessible. Make public, or annotate with @FXML"

and the program doesn't want to start up or even show me my stage.

LoginController:

```
   @FXML private void initialize (ActionEvent event)
 {
      System.out.println("test");  
 }
```

if i simply delete the code "onAction="#initialize" my program runs and shows me an interface, but my button to login doesn't work(obviously)

P.S. making it public doesnt work

any advice will appreciated thanks a lot in advance

code:

Main:

```
public class Login extends Application
{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Login");
    stage.show();
}
```

Controller:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label lblmessage;

@FXML
private TextField txtUsername;

@FXML
private Button btnLogin;

@FXML
private PasswordField txtPassword;

   @FXML private void handlebutton()
   {
   System.out.println("test");    
  }

  /**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}



}
```

Comment: What runtime exceptio do you get?

Comment: Javafx launcher error: exception while running application!!! This was with out deleting the onnaction section of the fxml! When I dleetd this section the programme kaunches, but with no functionality to the button of coarse

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace.

Comment: Executing C:\Users\CasperG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login FC\dist\run966869135\Login FC.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre/bin/java
Page language not specified.
file:/C:/Users/CasperG/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Login%20FC/dist/run966869135/Login%20FC.jar!/fxml/Login.fxml:14
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:510)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:594)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
 etec
  
  
  
  at fxml.Login.start(Login.java:24)    @Puce

Answer (score 1):

I guess the method name is the problem. 
The method `@FMXL protected void initialize()` may be used as an additional callback on startup.
You can use the `initialize` method e.g. to dynamically fill your UI.

So:
Try to rename the method in code and fxml file.

---

As given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm):

> An instance of the FXMLLoader class simply looks for the initialize() 
>   method on the controller and calls it, if available. Note that, similar to other FXML callback methods such as event handlers, this method must be annotated with the @FXML annotation if it is not public.

---

I have just rebuilt your code. I also added this main method to the Login:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
```

This is the Login.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LoginController">
  <children>
    <Label fx:id="lblmessage" text="Label" />
    <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" />
    <Button fx:id="btnLogin" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlebutton" text="Button" />
    <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

And with this setup, everything works as expected.
The Stage is loaded, the handlebutton method is called when I click the button and the initialize method is called on startup.
The error currently seems to be not reproducable.

Comment: I have tried changing the name of the method to several different ones! Error goes away when I remove the # but the programme still doesn't run! It only runs if I remove the whole onaction section! Tried initially @FXML private void btnLoginAction ()

Comment: @CasperGermishuys I have just re-checked. This is exactly the way I am doing it in my application which works fine. Maybe providing a little more code and the StackTrace can help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all! my issue was that in my fxml file i was naming my textfields/password fields fields

```
 <TextField id="txtUsername"....... etc
 <Label id="lblmessage" ...... etc
 <PasswordField id="txtPassword".... etc
```

therefore i received a null pointed everytime a null pointer everytime i tried to access those variable from my controller/main class, because my program wasnt recieving any data because i forgot my fX:id, so the above should have looked like the following

```
  <TextField fx:id="txtUsername"....... etc
 <Label fx:id="lblmessage" ...... etc
 <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword".... etc
```

then my program worked perfectly
thanks everyone for their help